# JQuery File Upload, check max number of files before upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Question about Blueimp JQuery File Upload (UI version) using PHP.

I've set the max_number_of_files with a CustomUploadHandler (index.php) and it works fine. My problem is that the user is only told (error) that the maximum number of files has been exceeded AFTER the uploads are complete. This is a waste of time and resources when uploading large files, so there must be a way around this that I am missing. It would be neat to use the fileuploadadd callback function for instance, but at that point the relevant error (Maximum number of files exceeded) has not occurred.

Is it possible to access the value of max_number_of_files and the current number of files already uploaded from a fileuploadadd callback function? Or is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

In Change function of fileupload try this code.

```
change : function (e, data) {
    if(data.files.length>=5){
       //Custom code
        return false;
    }
}
```